# The Live stream Plugin - When people share it post to wall. the link back does not go to my site,instead my fb app, how to make go to my site?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Newbee - The Live stream Plugin - When people share in the discussion it posts to their wall. The link back from their wall does not go to my site,instead to my fb app. I do not want this. How to make the link go to my site?

Here is my meta tags, do not know if you need this to help.

```
<meta property="fb:222552801135886" content="{222552801135886}"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Green Zone Kicker" />
<meta property="og:type" content="book" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.greenzonekicker.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.greenzonekicker.com/img/bookforSale60.JPG" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Green Zone Kicker" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002932010605" />
```

Here is the code for my live stream plugin.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>    (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=222552801135886&xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-live-stream" data-event-app-id="222552801135886" data-width="873" data-height="500"  data-always-post-to-friends="false"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Also , I was just going with the flow and made a fb app for my site. But I dont get what that is doing for in terms of its usefulness? Can someone explain under what circumstance I would want my website to be embedded in my faceBook app?

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to put your url in BOTH (in my case"http://www.greenzonekicker.com/") in both the app > edit app > url and in the live stream plugin wizard where is says Via Attribution URL (?).

SO I put the above in both places, and now when someone shares in my discussion and goes to their wall, the link back does not go to a fan page or the embedded app, it will go straight to your site.

So to clarify, put the url your want the link to go to in BOTH the live stream code generator from facebook, AND in facebook > app > app name > edit > website > url.
I have heard of problems if you do not put the trailing forward slash after your url, so just do it to be safe.

Adam